# Can I split this file into sections by string while avoiding the multi-line array powershell behavior?

Tags: powershell

I have the text printout of a DISA STIG. It looks like this:

```
Group ID (Vulid):  V-96855
Group Title:  SRG-NET-000018-RTR-000001
Rule ID:  SV-105993r1_rule
Severity: CAT II
 Rule Version (STIG-ID):  CISC-RT-000010
Rule Title: The Cisco router must be configured to enforce approved authorizations for controlling the flow of information within the network based on organization-defined information flow control policies.
...
_____________________________________________________________

 Group ID (Vulid):  V-96857
Group Title:  SRG-NET-000025-RTR-000020
Rule ID:  SV-105995r1_rule
Severity: CAT II
 Rule Version (STIG-ID):  CISC-RT-000020
Rule Title: The Cisco router must be configured to implement message authentication for all control plane protocols.
...
_____________________________________________________________

 Group ID (Vulid):  V-96859
Group Title:  SRG-NET-000025-RTR-000085
Rule ID:  SV-105997r1_rule
Severity: CAT II
 Rule Version (STIG-ID):  CISC-RT-000030
Rule Title: The Cisco router must be configured to use keys with a duration not exceeding 180 days for authenticating routing protocol messages.
...
```

I'd like to process this, but I'm running into problems with how powershell treats multiline inputs. I'm trying to separate each rule (between the ____ dividers) into it's own section, and then turn it into xml. When I import the content and try to split it, it either comes out one line at a time, meaning that I can't really process the divider very well, or I've tried to encode it as a string, in which case each character comes out at a time.

```
    $rawContent = Get-Content C:\Users\ncfx\Projects\SignatureRWK\raw.txt -Raw

    $splitRules = $rawContent.Split("_____________________________________________________________")

    Foreach ($rule in $splitRules) {
        $rulectArr = $rule.split(":")
        $processedContent += @"
    <Rule>
        <Group ID>$($rulectArr[1])</Group ID>
#...
"@
```

Desired Output:

```
<GroupId>V-96197</GroupId>
<GroupTitle>SRG-APP-000026-NDM-000208</GroupTitle>
<RuleId>SV-105335r1_rule</RuleId>
```

Actual Output:

```
<GroupId>V-96197</GroupId>
<GroupTitle></GroupTitle>
<RuleId></RuleId>
...
<GroupId>SRG-APP-000026-NDM-000208</GroupId>
<GroupTitle></GroupTitle>
<RuleId></RuleId>
```

I've also tried using regular expressions without much success (though I will be the first to admit that I'm very bad at those.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise solution:

```
((Get-Content -Raw raw.txt) -split '\r?\n_+\r?\n\r?\n') | ForEach-Object { 
  @"
<Rule>
$(
  $(foreach ($line in $_ -split '\r?\n' -ne '') {
    $name, $value = $line -split '(?: \(.+?\))?: +'
    $name = $name -replace ' '
    "  <$name>$value</$name>"
  }) -join "`n"
)
</Rule>
"@
}
```

With your sample input, the above yields:

```
<Rule>
  <GroupID>V-96855</GroupID>
  <GroupTitle>SRG-NET-000018-RTR-000001</GroupTitle>
  <RuleID>SV-105993r1_rule</RuleID>
  <Severity>CAT II</Severity>
  <RuleVersion>CISC-RT-000010</RuleVersion>
  <RuleTitle>The Cisco router must be configured to enforce approved authorizations for controlling the flow of information within the network based on organization-defined information flow control policies.</RuleTitle>
  <...></...>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <GroupID>V-96857</GroupID>
  <GroupTitle>SRG-NET-000025-RTR-000020</GroupTitle>
  <RuleID>SV-105995r1_rule</RuleID>
  <Severity>CAT II</Severity>
  <RuleVersion>CISC-RT-000020</RuleVersion>
  <RuleTitle>The Cisco router must be configured to implement message authentication for all control plane protocols.</RuleTitle>
  <...></...>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <GroupID>V-96859</GroupID>
  <GroupTitle>SRG-NET-000025-RTR-000085</GroupTitle>
  <RuleID>SV-105997r1_rule</RuleID>
  <Severity>CAT II</Severity>
  <RuleVersion>CISC-RT-000030</RuleVersion>
  <RuleTitle>The Cisco router must be configured to use keys with a duration not exceeding 180 days for authenticating routing protocol messages.</RuleTitle>
  <...></...>
</Rule>
```

Explanation:

- `-split '\r?\n_+\r?\n\r?\n'` splits the input file's entire contents into blocks of lines by the separator lines (`___...`)
- The `ForEach-Object` call then uses an expandable here-string (`@"<newline>..."`) to create a `<Rules>` element from the individual lines in the block:

  - `$_ -split '\r?\n' -ne ''` splits each block into individual lines, filtering out empty lines.
  - `$name, $value = $line -split '(?: \(.+?\))?: +'` splits each line into name and value, by separator `:` followed by one more spaces, optionally preceded by a substring in `(...)`
  - `$name = $name -replace ' '` removes all spaces from the name.
  - Expandable string `"  <$name>$value</$name>"` constructs the XML element for the line at hand.
  - `` -join "`n" `` joins all XML element lines with newlines; if you want to use the platform-appropriate newline sequence instead of `` "`n" `` (LF-only), use `[Environment]::NewLine`

Answer (score 1):

I think my approach would be a bit different:

1. Read each line in;
2. If the line contains a `:` character, try to parse it into a key-value pair dynamically (rather than hard-coding each field), and save that until later;
3. If the line is `_____________________________________________________________`, eject all of the saved key-value pairs;
4. If neither of the above is true, do nothing;
5. After all lines are read, eject any remaining key-value pairs.

Something similar to this:

```
# A container to hold all of the items:
$items = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[object]'
# Each item will be a series of key-value pairs in this dictionary:
$item = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]'
Get-Content C:\Temp\linex.txt |% {
  if ($_ -like '*:*') {
    # This is a new key-value pair.
    $linesplit = $_ -split ':'
    # Take out anything in parentheses (), plus any spaces, to make the field name.
    $fieldname = $linesplit[0] -replace '\([^)]*\)', '' -replace ' ',''
    # Since the field contents may contain ':' characters, join them back together.
    # The trim has to happen after the join (so ": " doesn't become ":").
    $item[$fieldname] = ($linesplit[1..($linesplit.Count-1)] -join ':').Trim()
  } elseif ($_ -eq '_____________________________________________________________') {
    # Found an item separator; add this item to the bucket of items.
    $items.Add($item)
    # Prepare the dictionary to receive the new item.
    $item.Clear()
  }
}
# Read all of the lines; if there are any kvp left, add them to the list, too.
if ($item.Count -gt 0) {
  $items.Add($item)
  Remove-Variable item
}
```

At this point, there's a variable, `$items`, with all of the rules. Now to get it into XML. The default XML writing is a bit ugly, so you could use something like this to produce it:

```
"<Rules>`r`n $($items |% {
  " <Rule>`r`n $(
    foreach ($key in $_.Keys) {
      "    <$key>$($_[$key])</$key>`r`n"
    }
  )  </Rule>`r`n"
})</Rules>"
```

This gives:

```
<Rules>
  <Rule>
     <GroupID>V-96859</GroupID>
     <GroupTitle>SRG-NET-000025-RTR-000085</GroupTitle>
[...]
```